# Not able to click element which is in div and hidden

Tags: html, hidden

I am not able to click the element which is in div and is hidden. Tried Action builder and JS executor still not able to click. Below is the html sample.

This is partial html i have shared. On mouse hover the "Simulate button" will active to click.
Please do help me.

```
<div id="isc_MR" style="POSITION:relative;VISIBILITY:inherit;Z-INDEX:204302;CURSOR:pointer;" eventproxy="isc_Button_105">
     <table width="100%" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" 
       style="table-layout:fixed;overflow:hidden;">
     <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td class="button" valign="center" nowrap="true" align="center" 
             onfocus="isc_Button_105.$47()" tabindex="-1" '="" style="padding-
             top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;">
             <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
             <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="button" 
             style="margin:0px;border:0px;padding:0px;background-
             image:none;background-color:transparent;font-size:1px;padding-
             right:6px"><img width="16" height="16" border="0" align="absmiddle" 
             suppress="TRUE" eventpart="icon" style="vertical-align:middle" 
             name="isc_MRisc_Button_105$4u" src="http://test2.mond-
             cloud.com/mond03/images/silk/simulate.png">
           </td>
           <td class="button" nowrap="true" 
            style="margin:0px;border:0px;padding:0px;background-
            image:none;background-color:transparent;">Simulate</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can someone help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can someone help me how to resolve this issue? I am stuck and awaiting help from you guys.Please if you know the answer help me.